# Which plugin I need to use to read aztecs via a MobileFist app?

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ibm-mobilefirst, ionic-v1, aztec-barcode

I'm trying a lot of plugins that I find on the net to read aztec codes through the phone's camera, but none of these works.

Using MobileFirst, I can not integrate other versions of cordova, so which plugin do you recommend using according to your experiences?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You have not mentioned which version of MFP you have tried, but MFP 8.0 allows you to integrate with different versions of Cordova.

You can install the latest mfpdev-cli, Cordova and latest MFP SDK to try out.

Details on MFP 8.0 Cordova SDK [here](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/cordova-tutorials/).

Comment: I use MFP v7.1 that doesn't allow to integrate other version of Cordova than the inner one.

Comment: MFP 7.1 does not. You should try out MFP 8.0, which gives what you need plus lot more.

Comment: I cannot use MFP 8.

Comment: With 7.1, you cannot change or switch to another Cordova. See if there are plugins that work with the Cordova version MFP 7.1 ships.